# php X-mailer: mail sent twice

Tags: php, email

I prepared a form and a php code that send a confirmation e-mail.

here's the code I tried:

```
$mail_boundary = "=_NextPart_" . md5(uniqid(time()));
$sender = "postmaster@mysite.it";
'''
$text_msg = "messaggio in formato testo";
$html_msg = "<b>messaggio</b> in formato <p><a href='http://www.aruba.it'>html</a><br><img src=\"http://hosting.aruba.it/image_top/top_01.gif\" border=\"0\"></p>";

$msg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$msg .= "--$mail_boundary\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$msg .= "\r\n";
'''
$msg .= "\n--$mail_boundary\n";
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$msg .= "<br><br>";
'''
$msg .= "\n--$mail_boundary--\n";
$headers = "From: $sender\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n\tboundary=\"$mail_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP " . phpversion();
if(mail('my-mail', "Summary from $name", $msg, $headers, "-f$sender")) {
    mail($email, "Summary", $msg, $headers, "-f$sender");
    header("Refresh: 5; url=landing_page");
    echo "Mail sent.<br>";
    echo "You're being redirected.";
}
else {
    echo "Error"
}
```

Once the form is submitted, the php code send doubled email.
I want one e-mail to me, and another to the customer.
How can i solve the issue of doubled email?

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to solve the issue of email sent twice

Comment: It's very likely you have a browser plugin that is submitting your request more than once. Add some logging to confirm that.

Comment: Can you please explain me how to collect log?

Comment: Please read: [mcve] And reduce your question as minimal as possible

Answer (score 1):

The mail command is called twice so the email will send twice.
What you want is something like

```
$m = mail($email, "Summary from $name", $msg, $headers, "-f$sender");

if($m) {
    header("Refresh: 5; url=landing_page");
    echo "Mail sent.<br>";
    echo "You're being redirected.";
}
else {
    echo "Error"
}
```

Comment: quoting myself, "I want one e-mail to me, and another to the customer". I call the mail function twice because i want 2 email. But the result is 2 mail to me, 2 mail to the customer

Comment: Ah apologies. Again back to a plugin issue. Perhaps your mail and customer mail are the same?

Comment: No, I'm trying with different mails. The good news is that with a different pc, they're not doubled. But there's a solution in order to avoid the problem for every browser and plugin?

Comment: So we think it's a plugin/browser issue. Ok. Well. Can you check your logs or use the developer tools in the browser. I suspect that the plugin won't send any post data (maybe) so you can add some validation around your mail action and that'll sort it. Even something simple as $_POST['action'] == 'submit' and then having that around the mail statement might sort it.